# tufte-book problem

Tags: titles, tufte

When I try to run the following code,

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{amsfonts, soul, microtype}

\title{A Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I get many errors, mostly about fonts.

I am using an iPad Pro and TeXPad. I haven't tried running it on my desktop as I do all my work on the iPad. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: "I get many errors, mostly about fonts." is not very informative. Care to elaborate?

Comment: D.G. As a rank neophyte, I am not really sure how to answer your question, but here is a screenshot of a major poertion of the error message list:: (Sorry, I have to figure out how to upload a screenshot,. I will respond shortly.

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to upload a screenshot on my iPad, but I did notice that the .pdf of the (failed) compilation had text saying that it was a Soul error. That's the reason I loaded the package Soul, but received the same errors.

Comment: The example code you provided compiled successfully for me. Can you provide a more complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Here is the original example I tried to run. It is a cut and paste from a web site: (The web site here said it was 273 characters too lone. Kinda' hard to respond with such limitations. Clearly, I don't really know how to interact with the stack exchange software. Sorry. But the more complex code gives the same result: errors on the \maketitle command.

Comment: Could you post the exact text of the first error that you get? That would be a start to try to understand the problem. You can add information to your question by pressing the `edit` button at the bottom of the main question text.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SE of course :)

Comment: This MWE runs fine on my mac mini under TeXshop, so I suppose it is a problem with the TeXPad-iPad combination. Unless someone here has that combination running (in which case I would be indebted if they would give it a try!), I will try a more appropriate forum. Thanks a lot to you guys who responded.